# Memory error в Numpy при попытке реализовать "One-Hot-Encoding"

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, memory, numpy, big-data

```
import numpy as np
import codecs

fileObj = codecs.open("fragments.txt", "r", "utf_8_sig")
text = fileObj.read()
fileObj.close()

strings = text.split('\n')

char_dictionary = np.load('bag_of_characters.npy').item()
START_SYM = 165
END_SYM = 166
UNK = 167
SPACE_SYM = 168
CHARACTER_SYM = 169
train_size = len(strings)
dict_len = len(char_dictionary) + 5

MAX_LENGTH = 130

def char_to_code(char):
    if char in char_dictionary.keys():
        return char_dictionary[char]
    else:
        return UNK

data = np.zeros(shape=(train_size, MAX_LENGTH, dict_len),dtype='float32')
for i in range(train_size):
    for pos, char in enumerate(strings[i]):
            data[i, pos, char_to_code(char)] = 1
```

Пытаюсь преобразовать стоки в numpy массив с помощью one-hot-encoding на character уровне. В массиве 1.6кк строк при попытке преобразовать более +-200к строк выдает memory error.У меня вопрос в том, это физический предел моего ПК(8 гб) или можно как то обойти эту ошибку?
**Спасибо.**

Comment: Если второй питон, то попробуйте заменить `range(train_size)` на  `xrange(train_size)`

Comment: Вы можете пояснить зачем делать "one-hot-encoding" на уровне единичных символов? Что вам это даст?

Comment: если гуглить, то seq2seq character-level, проще говоря меня интересуют последовательности символов

Comment: @AliaksandrNazarau, добавил и такой вариант...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем изобретать колесо? Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

Пример:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk import sent_tokenize

text = """Пытаюсь преобразовать стоки в numpy массив с помощью one-hot-encoding на character уровне. В массиве 1.6кк строк при попытке преобразовать более +-200к строк выдает memory error. У меня вопрос в том, это физический предел моего ПК(8 гб) или можно как то обойти эту ошибку? Спасибо."""

sents = sent_tokenize(text)

vect = CountVectorizer()
X_vect = vect.fit_transform(sents)
```

Результат:

```
In [6]: X_vect.A
Out[6]:
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)

In [7]: vect.get_feature_names()
Out[7]:
['200к',
 '6кк',
 'character',
 'encoding',
 'error',
 'hot',
 'memory',
 'numpy',
 'one',
 'более',
 'вопрос',
 'выдает',
 'гб',
 'или',
 'как',
 'массив',
 'массиве',
 'меня',
 'моего',
 'можно',
 'на',
 'обойти',
 'ошибку',
 'пк',
 'помощью',
 'попытке',
 'предел',
 'преобразовать',
 'при',
 'пытаюсь',
 'спасибо',
 'стоки',
 'строк',
 'то',
 'том',
 'уровне',
 'физический',
 'это',
 'эту']
```

PS `CountVectorizer` по умолчанию возвращает разреженную матрицу в качестве результата - обычно она занимает на несколько порядков меньше памяти по сравнению с обычными Numpy NDArray.

```
In [9]: X_vect
Out[9]:
<3x39 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 40 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [10]: type(X_vect)
Out[10]: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

---

**UPDATE:**  One-hot-encoding на уровне единичных символов:

```
In [22]: vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)[\w\d]{1}')

In [23]: X_vect = vect.fit_transform(sents)

In [24]: ''.join(vect.get_feature_names())
Out[24]: '01268acdeghimnoprtuyабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфчшщыьэюя'

In [25]: X_vect
Out[25]:
<3x49 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 77 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Спасибо хороший вариант, не уверен что разряженная матрица подходит для обучения  rnn.По крайней мере в tutorialах keras делали ohe-hot

Comment: @AliaksandrNazarau, https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/5o2u06/how_to_pass_sparse_matrix_numpy_array_to_keras/